# Vuex not reactive when mutate

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have an array `tour_plan` in my `state` which contains an object(s).

```
tour_plan = [
    {
        day:1,
        location_id:3,
        location_name:'Colombo'
    }
]
```

I want to make this object

```
tour_plan = [
    {
        day:1,
        location_id:3,
        location_name:'Colombo',
        tour_id:3,
        tour_name:'City tour'
    }
]
```

After gothourgh the docs in vuex in figureout that this won't work in reactive manner in vuex mutations.

```
state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1].tour_id = payload.tour_id;
state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1].tour_name = payload.tour_name;
```

So I tried these 2 ways.

```
state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1] = { ...state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1],
                tour_id: payload.tour
             };

Vue.$set(state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1], 'tour_id', payload.tour);
```

But non of them also doesn't work.
Where is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the fact you can't mutate an object/array item by index access without "breaking" the reactivity system.

About what You've tried, according to the documentation of [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set), it expects as first argument the entire object/array rather than the length.

So the correct manner is:

```
Vue.$set(state.tour_plan, 0, payload.tour);
```

where 0 is the index of the element you want to update(replace)

Comment: Thanks for your clue with the help of your answer I found a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
   Vue.set(state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1], 'tour_id', payload.tour)
   Vue.set(state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1], 'tour_payment', payload.tour_payment)
   Vue.set(state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1], 'tour_name', payload.tour_name)
```